# DECLARE vs. Direct DateTime Conversion Performance Comparison

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, datetime-conversion

I am trying to understand if there is any performance difference between declaring a datetime conversion variable and using it versus directly converting the date in a SQL Server query.

Here are two example queries:
Query 1: Do DateTime Conversion Every Time

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestMessages
WHERE CreatedDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2023-12-18 00:00:00', 120);
```

Query 2: DECLARE DateTime Conversion Variable

```
DECLARE @yourDateString NVARCHAR(19) = '2023-12-18 00:00:00';
DECLARE @ConvertedDate DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @yourDateString, 120);

SELECT * 
FROM TestMessages
WHERE CreatedDate > @ConvertedDate;
```

Is there any noticeable performance difference between these two queries? How does declaring a variable for datetime conversion impact the execution time of the query? Additionally, what SQL Server tools or techniques can be used to analyze and measure this performance difference?

I've been experimenting with two different approaches in my SQL Server queries for datetime conversion. In one query, I directly convert the datetime value, and in another, I use DECLARE to create a conversion variable. I expected to observe a potential difference in performance between these two methods, but the results were not as clear as I anticipated. I would like insights on the performance implications of these approaches and any recommended practices for optimizing datetime conversions in SQL Server queries.

When I examine the Execution Plans, there seems to be a difference in the plan, but it's unclear whether it's significant. Additionally, when I look at the statistics, it shows '88 rows affected' for the first query, while it shows '1 rows affected' for the other. The cost is shown as 100% and 0.000s for the first query with '88 of 88 (0%) rows affected.' However, for the second query, the cost is also 100%, but '0.000s 0 of 855 (0%)' rows are affected. Is this discrepancy significant?

Comment: And under what circumstances would you active able to hardcode the date rather than using a parameter?

Comment: When you ran both queries a fixed number of times each and recorded the time it took to execute each one, what were the results?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With

```
WHERE CreatedDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2023-12-18 00:00:00', 120);
```

the cardinality estimates will likely be more accurate.

This will improve the chances of getting an appropriate plan and, potentially,  memory grant.

For the `CreatedDate > @ConvertedDate` predicate it will just assume 30% will match unless you also use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to allow it to sniff the variable's value.

For `CreatedDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2023-12-18 00:00:00', 120)` it can look that value up in the histogram and get estimates from there.

```
CREATE TABLE TestMessages
             (
                          CreatedDate DATETIME INDEX ix_CreatedDate,
                          Filler      CHAR(1000) NULL
             )
INSERT TestMessages
       (CreatedDate)
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, value, '1990-01-01 00:00:00')
FROM   generate_series(1, 300000)
```

**WHERE CreatedDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2023-12-18 00:00:00', 120);**

[image]

**WHERE CreatedDate > @ConvertedDate**

[image]

**WHERE CreatedDate > @ConvertedDate OPTION (RECOMPILE);**

[image]

Comment: "it will just assume 30%" I think it actually still used the density vector (ie the average rowcount for any random value)

Comment: @Charlieface not for a greater than.  All it knows is that you are picking a range greater than any unknown value. You aren't selecting equal to any specific value.

Comment: Ah good point missed the inequality.

Comment: Here be a hidden gold nugget. @Martin Smith could you tell me where the 30% assumption comes from?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis It's just a hardcoded guess for `<` and `>` when one side is a variable and no `recompile` hint that has survived in the product in this case for as long as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

For exploring the performance impact of parameters in queries:

```
WHERE CreatedDate > @ConvertedDate
```

When a variable is used in the `WHERE` clause, the optimizer creates an execution plan for the first parameter value that is passed. For example, when `@ConvertedDate='2020-03-10 10:30:00.000'` is passed for the first time, then the optimal execution plan is created by the optimizer. This plan might just be the best fit for this value. Next time, for another value of `@ConvertedDate`, the previous plan is used, which may not be optimal for that value.

In other words, the created plan, which was optimal for the first value, may be sub-optimal for other values.

So, the query may run poorly and slowly. This is known as parameter sniffing. There are several ways to overcome this problem:

[Parameter Sniffing](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/parameter-sniffing/)

Anyway, the execution plan is similar for both queries:

```
WHERE CreatedDate > @ConvertedDate
```

or

```
WHERE CreatedDate > '2020-03-10 10:30:00.000'
```

[image: Execution plan]

Here is [a sample with the execution plans](https://dbfiddle.uk/TYNHYs4A)

Comment: This is incorrect. Variables and parameters are not the same. Variables are not sniffed like parameters. Indeed assigning to variables is one way of defeating parameter sniffing as acts like `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)`

Comment: @MartinSmith Most of the time the value is not fixed, and we have to deal with parameters. Assume that the query is executed from an application. So we have to options: Replacing the value in the query string or passing it as a parameter.

Comment: Find a question about parameters to give this answer to then. This question is specifically about variables. It mentions the word "variable" four times and parameter zero times and the code example given is using a variable. I agree parameters are more common but variables still have a place, the scenario in the question can come up if running a script in SSMS and wanting to be DRY and not repeat a date used multiple times

Comment: @MartinSmith I appreciate your point of view. The scenario I intended to describe was added to my answer.